# How to not repeat a table column based on JOIN query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

To put simply, this is what my index.php page looks like:

```
[comment_id 10]
[commenter_name here]
    [reply_id 1]
    [replier_name here]

[comment_id 10]
[commenter_name here]
    [reply_id 2]
    [replier_name here]

[comment_id 10]
[commenter_name here]
    [reply_id 3]
    [replier_name here]
```

This is how I need it to look like:

```
[comment_id 10]
[commenter_name here]
    [reply_id 1]
    [replier_name here]
    [reply_id 2]
    [replier_name here]
    [reply_id 3]
    [replier_name here]
```

What my code does: when reply button is clicked, a reply to the comment_id is submitted to my `replies` table in my database. The issue: maybe I'm incorrectly writing my `SELECT` statement based on the type of JOIN being used, but my `comment_id`'s are being repetitively echoed out along with the replier_names. The result should only be: each unique comment_id with all replier_names echoed underneath. This is a dummy version of my long code:

```
$sid = $_SESSION['userid'];
$query = $conn->query("
    SELECT comments.*, replies.*, users.username
    FROM comments
    LEFT JOIN replies
    ON comments.comid = replies.repcomid
    INNER JOIN users
    ON comments.comuserid = users.userid
    ORDER BY comments.comid DESC;
");
$comreps = [];
while($row = $query->fetch_object()) {
  $comreps[] = $row;
}
?>

<?php foreach($comreps as $comrep): ?>
    <b><?php echo $comrep->username; ?></b>
    <div><?php echo $comrep->repname; ?></div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

@Tim Morton: Just wondering, is this the exact method you are referring to? (See below)

```
<?php
$last_username = '';
foreach($comreps as $comrep):
    if ($comrep->username != $last_username): ?>
        <b><?php echo $comrep->username; ?></b>
    <?php endif;
    $last_username = $comrep->username; ?> 
    <div><?php echo $comrep->repname; ?></div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: @MosesSchwartz But my question includes php code and select queries from my database. I don't think php code can be visible on fiddle?

Comment: Two ways to approach it: put all comments in an array and then query replies as you loop through them, or put the whole thing in an array using user id as a key, I.e., `$row[$comid][‘relies’] = ` array of replies.  I would lean towards the more oop-ish first option.

Comment: @TimMorton Hi, I've added a block of code to the end of my question. Is that the exact method you are referring to, unless you mean something else?

Comment: That’s the same idea as the second suggestion, just without the overhead of the array.

Comment: @TimMorton I'm still a little confused. Could you demonstrate how to do your first method? Because the method I showed you affects the javascript on my code, which is why I can't use it.

Comment: Your simplified code doesn’t have any JavaScript;  what you have should work fine. I’ll put up a couple of examples, but the way I picture the first one is with dedicated models for each table (active record style), so it may be more pseudo code...   I’m using a phone, so this may take a while ;)

Comment: @TimMorton oh this is just a dummy code. The full code including the javascript is  400 lines. I just checked something and feel like the issue is related to my javascript. But I really do appreciate your help on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three ways that I can think of:

1. Nested queries (outer loop is comments, inner loop is replies)
2. Build a data array from your current query
3. Use a temporary variable to hold the last comment info to display until the comment info changes

Each technique has pros and cons, so which way is best?  It depends...

### Temporary variable

You pretty much nailed #3 in your edit. This is probably the most efficient way to do it (one query, little overhead). The only downside is that it sticks more logic in the view than I like to put in (clutters up the view), and it’s completely procedural, but that’s a matter of taste.

### Data array

This also uses the single query, but uses a named array to aggregate the comments. Downside: the array itself can get confusing.

To start off, how would you represent the data if it were a json string?

```
[{
    comment:
    {
        commentor_id:’$comment_id’, 
        commentor_name:’$commentor_name’
    },{
        reply
        [
            {
                reply_id:’$reply_id1’,
                reply_name:’$reply_name1’
            }, {
                reply_id:’$reply_id2’,
                reply_name:’$reply_name2’
            }
        ]
    }
}]
```

(Side note, as I wrote this, the [duck](https://rubberduckdebugging.com/) has suggested a better way which I’ll show after this)

To make the array dedupe itself, I’d make one change:

```
[{$comment_id:{
    comment:
    {
        commentor_id:’$commentor_id’, 
        commentor_name:’$commentor_name’
    },{
        reply
        [{$reply_id1:
            {
                reply_id:’$reply_id1’,
                reply_name:’$reply_name1’
            }, {$reply_id2:
            {
                reply_id:’$reply_id2’,
                reply_name:’$reply_name2’
            }
        ]
    }
}]
```

Create this array as you iterate through the query results in your model:

```
$data = [];
while($row = $query->fetch_object()) {
    $data[$row->comid] = array(
        ‘comment_id’=>$row->comid,
        ‘comment_name’=>$row->username,
    );
    if(!isset($data[$row->comid][‘reply’]) {
        $data[$row->comid][‘reply’]=array();
    }
    $data[$row->comid][‘reply’][$row->repid] = array(
        ‘reply_id’=>$row->repid,
        ‘reply_name’=>$row->repname
    );

}
```

Then you can traverse the array structure in the view:

```
<?php foreach($data as $comments): ?>
    <div><?= $comments[‘comment_name’] ?></div>
    <ol>
        <?php foreach($comments[‘reply’] as $reply): ?>
            <li><?= $reply[‘reply_id’] ?></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ol>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

### Data array, part 2

The database can output the data the way you need it using [aggregate functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg). (I leave this for more study)

### Nested queries

This uses data access objects in a model. I don’t have enough room to explain, but consider each crud object to be capable of finding a record by its id

```
// assuming custom data access objects Comment and Reply each with method ‘find()’
<?php
$comment = new Comment (new DB);
$reply = new Reply(new DB);
?>


<?php $comment->find($comment_id); ?>
<?php while($row = $comment->fetch() ): ?>
    <div><?= $row->name?></div>
    <ol>
    <?php $reply->find($row->id); ?>             
    <?php while($r = $reply->fetch()): ?>
         <li><?= $r->name ?></li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ol>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Benefits: uses reusable objects and separates model and view

Downside: OOP can hide expensive database calls, especially when they are in loops. Practically, though, this isn’t a problem unless it gets way out of hand.

Comment: Oh wow, far more than I was expecting from a comment! These are some excellent solutions you provided, I'll definitely be implementing these with my code. And you have taught me so much today! Really, thank you so very much!!

Comment: @misner3456 feel free to upvote or accept if it's valuable to you.  Sorry the last one's a bit sparse; too much framework to add.  Glad to help :)

Comment: I forgot to mark as best answer, sorry about that! And thanks so much!